# Can the planets (graha) in the birth-chart in "Mrit Avastha" be activated through wearing gemstones?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, horoscopes, kundali

My ascendent is Scorpio (Vrischik). I have Mars in the 4th House in Aquarius, the Sun, the Moon, and Venus.  As per the Vedic chart, my mars is in '*mrit avastha*'. When I consulted, I was advised to wear gemstones.

I want to know whether planets (*grahas*) in '*mrit avastha*' be activated using gemstones only, or if other remedies are also there?